# Material UI TablePagination prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, pagination, warnings

Can anyone please help me what is the actual below warning and how to solve it?

Warning: Failed prop type: Material-UI: the page prop of a TablePagination is out of range (0 to 0, but the page is 10)

I expected a clear console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed prop type: Material-UI: the page prop of a TablePagination is out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61840990/failed-prop-type-material-ui-the-page-prop-of-a-tablepagination-is-out-of-rang)

Comment: @3ndless_____ let me check that method, thanks bud.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community The code is in my office laptop, Thats why i cant provide the actual code

Comment: @Madhan1021 did you solve this? If so could you please share your solution? I'm getting a similar message.